# Extended encoding function in Powershell for Google Charts

Tags: encoding, powershell, google-visualization

I have a function for simple encoding working fine in Powershell.  However, I require a function for extended encoding because I'll be plotting more than 62 points.  The Javascript function for extended encoding provided by google is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/data_formats.html#encoding_data)

Example of simple encoding function:

```
function simpleEncoding ($valueArray) {
$simpleEncoding = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

$total = 0
foreach ($value in $valueArray) {
    $total = $total + $value
}
for ($i = 0;$i -lt $valueArray.length;$i++) {

    $relativeValue = ($valueArray[$i] / $total)*62
    $relativeValue = [math]::round($relativeValue)

    $encodingValue = $simpleEncoding[$relativeValue]

    $Data = $Data + "" + $encodingValue

    }    
  return $data
}
```

So I'm looking for assistance in adapting the Javascript extended encoding function into Powershell.

Comment: What's the question? Are you not able to adapt the extendedencoding function in powershell as you did for the simpleencoding?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - I've just clarified the question.  The simple encoding is there as a reference should anyone else require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a working version:

```
Function Get-ExtendedEncoding {
Param (
    $dataArray,
    $maxValue
)

$ExtendedMap = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-.'
$MapLength = $ExtendedMap.length

 for ($i = 0;$i -lt $dataArray.length;$i++) 
{
    $numvalue = [int]$dataArray[$i]
    $scaledValue = $MapLength * $MapLength * $numvalue / $maxValue

    If($scaledValue -gt ($MapLength * $MapLength) -1)
        {
           $chartData += ".."
        }
     Elseif ($scaledValue -lt 0)
        {
            $chartData += '__'
        }
     Else 
        {
            $quotient = [Math]::Floor($scaledValue / $MapLength)
            $remainder = $scaledValue - $MapLength * $quotient
            $chartdata += $ExtendedMap[$quotient] + $ExtendedMap[$remainder]
        }
 }
        return $chartdata
 }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can get rid of classic for cycle using `foreach($data in $dataArray) { $numvalue = [int] $data ....}`